# Авторизация на сайте - не получаю cookie

Tags: c#, cookie

Пишу авторизацию на сайте(клиент для сайта) ru.leonbets.net/sportsbook. Всего передаётся 3 запроса.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во втором запросе передаются куки. Но вот как их "поймать" я не понимаю.

```
//авторизация (GET запрос)
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ru.leonbets.net");
req.Timeout = 1000000;

WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
string Out = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
string data = "do=login&doaction=1&trg=&cs=sportsbook&qs=&sport=&league=&toto_id=&oddval=&sbm=&match=&oddstype=&outcome=&tid=&login=oneill69%40YA.RU&password=*******";

//запрос (POST запрос)
req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ru.leonbets.net/login");
req.Method = "POST";
req.UserAgent = "Mozila/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; MyIE2;";
req.Timeout = 1000000;
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ru");
req.Accept = "image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*";
byte[] sentData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(data);
req.ContentLength = sentData.Length;

Stream sendStream = req.GetRequestStream();
sendStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);
sendStream.Close();

WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
string s = res.Headers["JSESSIONID"];
Stream ReceiveStream = res.GetResponseStream();
sr = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

//Кодировка указывается в зависимости от кодировки ответа сервера
Char[] read = new Char[256];
int count = sr.Read(read, 0, 256);
Out = String.Empty;
while (count > 0)
{
    String str = new String(read, 0, count);
    Out += str;
    count = sr.Read(read, 0, 256);
}
```

Насколько я понял для авторизации важно перехватить вот эту "печеньку"

```
string s = res.Headers["JSESSIONID"];
```

Но переменная s пуста - nill. Что я делаю не так? Помогите довести дело до конца.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. На этом сайте сделанно немного по другому:

1. Пользователь заходит на произвольную страницу сайта, при этом проверяется наличие cookie с уникальным ID сессии в качестве имени:

   - Если присутствует - пользователь попадает на необходимую страницу, при этом сервер устанавливает несколько cookies - tc_cookie, geotar, ipfrom, referer, и JSESSIONID. Выставляется  JSESSIONID не только после авторизации, но и просто во время переходов на страницы.
   - Если нет - выполняется динамический JavaScript, устанавливающий Cookie c id сессии в качестве имении, и вашим ip клиента в качестве значения. Если JavaScript не исполнился - пользователь видит ошибку гласящую о том, что у его браузер не обрабатывает JavaScript/не сохраняет Cookie.
2. Пользователь отправляет POST-запрос по адресу /login с urlencoded-контентом. Полями формы являются do=login, doaction=1, cs=sportsbook, login=<логин>, password=<пароль>. В ответ выставляются два Cookie - JSESSIONID(новый), и countrymode.
3. Если вход был удачным, то поля на странице появится информация о пользователе - так можно определить что пользователь успешно вошол.

Соответственно нам нужно иметь возможность разбора HTML и выполнения JavaScript. Для первого могу порекомендовать CSQuery либо AngleSharp. Для второго есть достаточно много пакетов, но так как JS на этом сайте очень простой и шаблонный, то можно воспользоватся и простым регулярным выражением.

Класс, корректно авторизующийся на этом сайте:

```
using AngleSharp.Dom;
using AngleSharp.Parser.Html;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LeonbetsPlayground
{
    class Leonbets : IDisposable
    {
        private const string USER_AGENT =
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) " +
            "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " +
            "Chrome/45.0.2414.0 Safari/537.36";

        private HttpClientHandler m_Handler;
        private HttpClient m_Client;

        public string UserName { get; private set; }
        public string AccountNumber { get; private set; }
        public string Balance { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Клиент. После авторизации можно его использовать для отправки/получения различной информации с сайта
        /// </summary>
        public HttpClient Client
        {
            get { return m_Client; }
        }

        public Leonbets()
        {
            m_Handler = new HttpClientHandler();

            m_Client = new HttpClient(m_Handler);
            m_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(USER_AGENT);
            m_Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://ru.leonbets.net/");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            m_Client.Dispose();
            m_Handler.Dispose();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Попытка авторизации. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="login">e-mail/id счета</param>
        /// <param name="password">Пароль</param>
        /// <returns>В случае удачной авторизации - true + заполнение информации о пользователе</returns>
        public async Task<bool> TryLogon(string login, string password)
        {
            await DoJavascriptValidation();

            var fields = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "do", "login" },
                    { "doaction", "1" },
                    { "cs", "sportsbook" },
                    { "login", login },
                    { "password", password }
                };

            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/login"))
            {
                request.Headers.Referrer = m_Client.BaseAddress;
                request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(fields);

                using (var response = await m_Client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    var html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    // проверяем наличие элементов с информацией о пользователе
                    var document = new HtmlParser(html).Parse();
                    var userInfo = document.QuerySelector("#user-info");

                    if (userInfo != null)
                    {
                        SetUserInfo(userInfo);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;   // Не авторизовались почему-то..
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Заполняем информацию о пользователе, раз уж уже получили её
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userInfoElement"></param>
        private void SetUserInfo(IElement userInfoElement)
        {
            this.UserName = userInfoElement.Children[0].TextContent;

            var accountInfo = userInfoElement.Children[1];
            this.AccountNumber = accountInfo.Children[1].TextContent;
            this.Balance = accountInfo.Children[3].TextContent;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// проверка на JavaScript
        /// </summary>
        private async Task DoJavascriptValidation()
        {
            // Получаем главную страницу, из JS получаем cookie
            var html = await m_Client.GetStringAsync("/");
            var cookie = GetCookieFromScript(html);
            m_Handler.CookieContainer.Add(m_Client.BaseAddress, cookie);

            await m_Client.GetStringAsync("/");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Получаем Cookie bp
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="html"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Cookie GetCookieFromScript(string html)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(html, @"setCookie\('(\w+)', '([\d\.]+)', (\d+)\);");
            var expiredays = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);

            return new Cookie()
            {
                Name = match.Groups[1].Value,
                Value = match.Groups[2].Value,
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(expiredays)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
using (var leonbets = new Leonbets())
{
    // при удачной авторизации
    if (await leonbets.TryLogon("test@example.com", "password"))
    {
        var client = leonbets.Client;
        // у нас есть авторизованый HTTP-клиент, с помощью которого мы можем выполнять различные полезные действия
    }
}
```

Comment: Функция `GetCookieFromScript` очень хрупкая[.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/276994)

Comment: @VladD, SetUserInfo ещё более хрупок, на самом деле. ) Да, можно было GetCookieFromScript заменить на нормальное выполнение JS через JInt или ClearScript, да в SetUserInfo стоило бы разбирать на ключ-значения на основе подзапросов. Да и вообще код отвратительно выглядит, да. Но мне лееень ) Да и как поломается - хоть какой-то стимул будет разобратся в том, как оно работает )

Comment: Хотелось бы иметь канонический ответ на тему «авторизация из кода на C#», с cookie/возможно js и всем таким, чтобы повесить на него метку [tag:faq] :) Я, например, ни разу не сталкивался с JInt и ClearScript.

Comment: @VladD, на этот вряд ли. Тут довольно много специфичного под конкретно для этот сайт. Работу же с JS на всяких браузерных игрушках демонстрировать хорошо - там без этого тяжело, а порой и совсем невозможно. Может потом что-нибудь отдельно напишу в виде вопроса-ответа, как наткнусь на что-нибудь более-менее интересное )

Comment: Не понимаю как подключить элементы AngleSharp.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov: Было бы классно, эта тема у нас тут не покрыта. Хотя, js-авторизация вида «проверить cookie, если нет, сгенерировать/запросить у сервера» — довольно популярное явление.

Comment: @НиколаКривошея, через NuGet - https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console - с открытым проектом открываете консоль менеджера пакетов, и набираете в ней `Install-Package AngleSharp`, ну и всё. Либо правой кнопкой на проекте, там выбираете "Mange NuGet Packages", в поиске набираете AngleSharp, выбираете найденный пакет, и жмете кнопку "Install"

Comment: Компилятор кричит на await leonbets.TryLogon("test@example.com", "password"). Говорит что "Оператор await можно использовать только в методах с модификатором async. Попробуйте пометить этот метод модификатором async и изменить тип его возвращаемого значения на Task." По идее на методе TryLogon уже стоит async. Не понимаю что ему не нравиться

Comment: @НиколаКривошея, Нет. Говорится о методе, из которого вы его вызываете - он должен быть тоже асинхронным(то что в "пример использования") и возвращать Task. Если же он синхронный, то можете в коде подождать завершение его выполнения, тупо заменив на `var task = leonbets.TryLogon("test@example.com", "password"); task.Wait();` в task.Result при этом будет результат выполнения метода. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh191443.aspx - статья на MSDN по использованию асинхронных методов.

Comment: @VladD написание ботов для букмекерского сайта в faq? так и до помощи в [ботоводстве ради халявных биткойнов недалеко](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428467/). между прочим leonbets.net явно запрещает использование ботов, так что любая помощь ботоводу - это потенциально лишь будущие вопросы "а как обойти еще и вот такое ограничение".

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну, авторизация на сайтах без API не так уж редко встречается здесь (на stackoverflow) как задание. Я скорее в этом, теоретическом смысле.