# Использование WebBrowser в фоновом потоке

Tags: c#, многопоточность, webbrowser, backgroundworker

Сразу скажу, что с

```
 webbrowser.Navigate("tra.ta");
```

проблем нет никаких. Проблемы начинаются с вот этого момента:

```
webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("switch_to_login_button").InvokeMember("click");
```

и так далее. Подскажите как использовать этот компонент в фоновом режиме, причем очень желательно чтобы работу было видно в GUI и он был живым. 
Из того, что пробовал:
1. Работа в backgroundworker, с параметром

```
 CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false.
```

2. Работа там же, используя

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
```

Не подошло, потому что не было смысла, все равно форма висит.
3. Создание нового экземпляра WebBrowser в backgroundworker. А также в потоке, создаваемом вот так:

```
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
{
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.Navigate("https://freebitco.in/");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    wb.Document.GetElementById("login_form_btc_address").SetAttribute("value", login.Text);
 });
 t.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
 t.Start();
```

4. Попытка установки Awesomium, закончившаяся неудачно, потому что VS не захотел принимать сборку, по неизвестной мне причине.

Если вспомню еще что пробовал, напишу, потому что способов перепробовал кучу, но так и не нашел решение. Весь день бьюсь.

UPD: Вот код, который я использую в потоке(как Thread, так и BackgroundWorker:

```
 System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {

            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                mainweb.Document.GetElementById("menu_drop").InvokeMember("click");
                mainweb.Document.GetElementById("drop1").Children[1].Children[0].InvokeMember("click");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                int losts = 0;
                int wins = 0;

                do
                {
                    mainweb.Document.GetElementById("double_your_btc_stake").SetAttribute("value", num.Text);

                    if (play(Convert.ToBoolean(button)))
                    {
                        wins++;
                        if (button == 0)
                        {
                            button = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            button = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        losts++;
                        num.Text = Convert.ToString(decimal.Parse(Convert.ToString((decimal.Parse(num.Text) * 2)), NumberStyles.Float));
                        mainweb.Document.GetElementById("double_your_btc_stake").SetAttribute("value", num.Text);
                    }
                    l_losts.Text = "Проигрышей: " + losts;
                    l_wins.Text = "Выигрышей: " + wins;
                } while (losts < Convert.ToInt32(max_losts.Text) && wins < Convert.ToInt32(max_wins.Text)); 
            }));
        });

        t.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
        t.Start();
```

Comment: По идее, все обращения к контролу должны быть в UI-потоке. `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false` — это как-то очень неправильно звучит. А что означает «все равно форма висит»? Здесь, пожалуйста, подробнее.

Comment: Поправил старт-пост. При выполнении этого кода висит форма.

Comment: Ну так, `Thread.Sleep(2000);` — неудивительно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы делаете что-то не то. Вы запускаете поток, а потом из этого потока снова перебрасываете код в UI-поток. Это всё равно, что произвести все действия в одном потоке.

Поскольку вам нужна пауза в 2 секунды (а нужна ли она вам реально? чего вы на самом деле дожидаетесь?), вам нужно сделать асинхронную функцию.

```
async Task Do()
{
    var doc = mainweb.Document;
    doc.GetElementById("menu_drop").InvokeMember("click");
    doc.GetElementById("drop1").Children[1].Children[0].InvokeMember("click");

    await Task.Delay(2000);

    int loses = 0, wins = 0;

    do
    {
        doc.GetElementById("double_your_btc_stake").SetAttribute("value", num.Text);

        // button надо превратить в bool
        if (play(button))
        {
            wins++;
            button = !button;
        }
        else
        {
            loses++;
            // вам точно нужен decimal? o_O
            // ну decimal.Parse после Convert.ToString вам точно не нужно
            decimal score = decimal.Parse(num.Text);
            score *= 2;
            num.Text = score.ToString();
            doc.GetElementById("double_your_btc_stake").SetAttribute("value", num.Text);
        }

        l_losts.Text = "Проигрышей: " + loses;
        l_wins.Text = "Выигрышей: " + wins;
    } while (losts < int.Parse(max_losts.Text) && wins < int.Parse(max_wins.Text));
}
```

Если ваша функция `play` блокирующая, переделайте и её в `Task<bool>` и вызывайте через `await`.

(Вообще, с типами переменных у вас что-то не в порядке, пересмотрите их. У вас слишком много конвертации туда и обратно.)

Comment: Я только начинаю учить этот язык, да и вообще по сути программировать, поэтому такие ответы важны. Делал как мог, пользуясь гуглом. А те конвертации нужны были для перевода цифры 0.00000001 из стринг, умножения и потом перевода обратно в стринг, а дополнительные конвертации нужны были для избавления от инженерного вида. А пауза по сути не нужна, сделал в целях безопасности, чтобы прогрузилась страница.
Сейчас разберусь с Task<bool>

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо, разобрался в этом вопросе!

Comment: Пожалуйста! Владеть async/await очень важно, всё современное асинхронное программирование на C# построено на нём.

Comment: Столько способов создать многопоточность. :)
А почему тогда MSDN позиционирует backgroundworker как наиболее приоритетный способ?
Или я неверно интерпретирую слова асинхронность и многопоточность?

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко: Так было когда-то давно. Начиная с C# 5, приоритетный способ — async/await.

Comment: О, спасибо, буду теперь знать, Вы очень мне помогли! Еще буквально один вопрос, а взаимодействие с формой потокобезопасное или нужно использовать блокирование на время изменения? И то же самое по поводу переменных, файлов и т.д.

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко: С формой можно взаимодействовать только в UI-потоке. Но при работе а async/await обычно нужные части функции (!) автоматически (!) выполняются в нужном потоке, так что проблем нет.

Comment: А если при работе в async\await два таска попробуют одновременно изменить какое-то значение в UI-потоке?
Хотя я только что подумал, что мне стоит просто побольше об этом почитать :)

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко: Ну, одновременно не получится, это ж один поток. Сначала по факту выполнится одно действие, потом другое.

Comment: То есть, без Exception, просто один поток(async) подождет пока закончит второй, грубо говоря?

Comment: async-методы работают не одновременно, а на время await «отпускают» поток, и в нём может выполниться другой async-метод. Попробуйте проэкспериментировать, запустив одновременно два разных `async Task Start(string str) { while (true) { await Task.Delay(500 + 100 * rand.Next(20)); button.Text = str; } }`.

Comment: Чувствую мне в этом долго разбираться, так что буду читать, экспериментировать и применять. Спасибо за ответы :)

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код перекидывает всю работу в главный поток (вызовом `BeginInvoke`).

Все от строки

```
mainweb.Document.GetElementById("menu_drop").InvokeMember("click");
```

и до завершения цикла `while` выполняется в главном потоке. Пока цикл не доработает до конца - главный поток занят, перерисовки не происходит и все "висит".

Вам надо разбить код на мелкие куски и выполнять их понемногу, чтобы между ними успевала отрабатывать отрисовка. Или еще как-то позволить приложению реагировать на события во время выполнения цикла. Два самых простых варианта:

1. Использовать таймер. То, что у вас сейчас в теле цикла, перенести в обработчик таймера. Т.е. вместо цикла вы получите своего кода для ставки раз в X миллисекунд, с отрисовкой между ними.
2. Или просто навставлять в коде цикла вызовов `Application.DoEvents()`. Каждый такой вызов даст возможность приложению обработать накопившиеся события, влючая отрисовку и клики.